# Ajax POST/GET request TO a python server

Tags: php, python, ajax, post

I am googleing around and trying, and I find no answer (I do not mean "How do I send POST requests using python?").

Story:

Developing a POS system I am already using python scripts to perform some tasks like communication with hardware peripherals. Until now these scripts are running on a small server with Apache installed and are started via POST request to an `ajax.php`, let's say with two params `$_POST['name']='scriptname'` and `$_POST['param1']=1200` which are transmitted over php command like `system('python ' . $_POST['name'] . '.py ' . $_POST['param1'] . ' &');` into `system('python scriptname.py 1200 &');`

Now I am thinking about to setup a pure Linux/Python server without Apache installed and want perform the same things.

Let's say, simpleHTTPserver is up and running for the specified folder.

1st question:

How can I manage it, so send POST (or for now let's say GET) requests from another network client to this server like `http://192.168.20.11:8080/scriptname.py?arg=1200`

2nd question:

How can I get a response like 'done' or a number like 1560 as response from the USB scale, to continue to work with the response (the ajax data part) on the sending network client?

Comment: You don't use SimpleHTTPServer, as its purpose it to serve local, static files. You should propably implement a wsgi application. Perhaps using something as Django or Flask.

Comment: I hope you are thinking about security vulnerabilities since someone can easily do `main.py & rm -rf` if they find about this endpoint. And I agree with @spectras on this. Use Django or Flask to develop your python webapp.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Apache?

Comment: @DanielRoseman "Why don't you want to use Apache?"... Good question. I am not absolutely sure yet, but I can imagine a performance speedup on very small hardware like bananapi or raspi.

Comment: Actually, even building a python application server (using Django, Flask or implementing the WSGI protocol yourself if you really want to), you still need a frontend server such as Apache or nginx. It is actually faster, it can do SSL/TLS termination for you, it is very good at fending off a lot of attacks (malformed request, connection exhaustion, …), it can serve static files directly from C code instead of going through your python app, it can work as a caching reverse proxy, it can do load-balancing, so you can launch several instances of your app and enjoy multiprocessing…

Comment: OK, for now I surrender :-)
Stay with Apache and will go into WebSockets. All the python stuff is to much for me at the moment.
Thanks for your answers, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Surrender ? Never !

Hours later... my very first python script, which still needs some hands on, some minor dents and scratches so far I can see, but it runs and serves me how I originally wanted it to do.

It is a kind of wrapper and server at the same time, contains some plausibility and security checks, which may be strengthened of course, and for now it accepts a single parameter, comma separated, a string (name of the desired subprocess script) and a number as parameter, like `sayhello,2000`. Still not yet JSON added, but currently no need for it.

It works without any python framework, but with a WSGIserver, clientside with jquery AJAX and CORS (tested with different URLs, not yet tested on different machines, as it will be necessary later on)

Hereby you'll find three files. The `ajax.html`, the `server.py` and the testscript `sayhello.py`.

Thanks for further hints, warnings or improvements in advance. Hope you like it.

ajax.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax POST to python</title>
</head>
<body>

    send message: <input type="text" id="message" value="" size="10" placeholder="string,number"> <input type=button id="send" value="send">
    <br />
    response: <span id="response"></span>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("input#send").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: $('input#message').val(),
        dataType: 'text',
        timeout: 3000,
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            $('span#response').html(responseData);
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            console.warn(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown);
            alert('failed - ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

server.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import threading
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from pathlib import Path
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

PORT = 8080
REQUEST_METHOD = "POST"

def myapp(env, http_stuff):
    if env['REQUEST_METHOD'] == REQUEST_METHOD:
        try:
            request_body_size = int(env['CONTENT_LENGTH'])
            request_body = env['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            request_body = "0"
        try:


#---------------------------security / plausibility
            allowed_scripts = ["sayhello","count_apples","get_scale_weight","etc."]
            el = request_body.split(",");
            arg_filename = str(el[0].strip())
            arg_num = int(el[1].strip())

            if not (arg_filename in allowed_scripts):           
                arg_filename = ""

            if isinstance(arg_num, int):
                arg_num = str(arg_num)
            else:
                arg_num = ""


#---------------------------script exists ?
            my_file = Path(arg_filename+".py")
            if my_file.is_file():
                output = "no valid output."


#---------------------------subprocess
                proc = Popen(["python", arg_filename+".py",arg_num], shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE )
                output = proc.communicate()[0]


#---------------------------more stuff
                response_body = output
            else:
                response_body = "["+request_body+"] is not allowed !"
        except:
            response_body = "some other error"
    else:
        response_body = "no POST data"
    status = '200 OK'


#---------------------------header with CORS support
    headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
            ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")]
    http_stuff(status, headers)
    return response_body

def start_server():
    httpd = make_server("", PORT, myapp)
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()
```

sayhello.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

print "I am sayhello.py and I say HELLO "+sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: That kindof defeats the point, doesn't it? The whole idea was to run the logic directly in your application server. Compare the complexity of your code to the 4 lines of [flask's hello](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/) for instance.

Comment: @spectras For sure you're totally right, if you point to an application server. May be I didn't explain good enough, for what do I need it:

Comment: @spectras An AMP based web app is running on the internet, users access it via iPad or Android tablet or regular desktop. My "application server" above is nothing more and nothing less then a hardware interface, which workarounds Apples limitation to certified hardware. One may call it an extendable and scalable printserver, which not only serves several printers, but also scales, barcode scanners a.s.o. Therefore I don't need Flask, Werkzeug, Jinja and and... May be later I 'll change my mind, but for now this simple WSGI server and some lines satisfy my needs.

Comment: @spectras I gave a try to flask... not that bad. Sometimes one should consider more calmful, which I did not. Now the app is running in flask, after some troubles with CORS, but now also AJAX and JSON run, and I am more than happy. Big deal with the URL-route to app name. Thanks to you for beeing unyielding :-)

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. Under the hood, Flask does pretty much what you did, except it handles all edge cases and has been thoroughly tried and tested. Makes it much more robust than anything you could hack manually yourself in reasonable time. Good old “standing on the shoulders of giants” thing :)